# Show $(p − 1)!=−1 [p] \iff p \text{ is prime.}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p ∈ \mathbb N, p ≥ 2$, show that :
>   $$(p − 1)!= −1 [p] \iff p \text{ is prime.}$$ 
>   Hint : For one direction, use the fact that $\mathbb F$ is a field and pair each element with its inverse.

I'm not sure where to start with this problem. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please learn to format on this site. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: We have $(4-1)=-1[4]$ but $4$ is not prime. Mor generally, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $(n-1)=-1[n]$ so the equivalence is not true.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't “$(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ if and only if $p$ is prime”? (Look up “Wilson's theorem”.)

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Wilson's Theorem.

For one direction, notice that if $p$ is prime, then we are looking at a field. Other than $1$ and $-1$, every element has a distinct inverse. $(p-1)!$ is the product of all the invertable elements of the field, so we can reorder and regroup the product as $1\cdot(a_1b_1)\cdots (a_kb_k)(p-1)$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are multiplicative inverses. Thus the product is $-1$.

For the other direction, if it's not a prime it's not a field and so there are zero divisors. We ca match up the units as before to see that they multiply to $-1$, but the product of zero divisors is always a zero divisor, so the total product is a zero divisor. Since $-1$ cannot be a zero divisor (it's always a unit), the product isn't $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of my favorite proof for the direction ($\Rightarrow$)

Suppose $(p − 1)!= −1 [p]$ then we have : $(p − 1)! +pU =-1 \Leftrightarrow -(p-1)!-pU=1$ with $U \in \mathbb{Z}$

So we have a form like this :

$(p-1)\times (p-2)...\times k\times...2\times 1 -pU=1$

According to Bachet-Bézout theorem we have for each $k\in \{1,...,p-1\}$, $\gcd(k,p)=1$ which means that $p$ is prime. Indeed $k<p$ and $k$ cannot divide $p$ because of Bachet-Bézout relations.

For the direction ($\Leftarrow$) you can see the answer of Stella Biderman who used the properties of field and inverses.